# Difference between a macro definition and function definition

Tags: function, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn Lisp but I got stuck by this example (you can find it on "ANSI Common Lisp", by Paul Graham, page 170):

```lisp
(defmacro in (obj &rest choices)
    (let ((insym (gensym)))
        `(let ((,insym ,obj))
             (or ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (c) `(eql ,insym ,c))
                           choices)))))
```

Graham then states:

> The second macro [...] `in` returns `true` if its first argument is `eql` to any of the other arguments. The Expression that we can write as:

```
(in (car expr) '+ '- '*)
```

> we would otherwise have to write as

```
(let ((op (car expr)))
    (or (eql op '+)
        (eql op '-)
        (eql op '*)))
```

Why I should write a macro when the following function I wrote **seems** to behave in the same way?

```
(defun in-func (obj &rest choices)
    (dolist (x choices)
        (if (eql obj x)
            (return t))))
```

I do not understand if I am missing something or, in this case, `in-func` is equivalent to `in`.

Comment: One thing you're missing is that `dolist` is *also* a macro, albeit a more complicated one.

Comment: geekosaur: yes, `dolist` is a macro, but in general there is a good point in avoiding writing *new* macros if you can do the same with functions.  Macros can make code harder for future readers since they don't follow the usual evaluation rules.  (But of course in this case `in` is defined as a macro exactly because of that.)

Comment: @Eli yep, that was exactly my concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The difference in using the macro vs function is in whether all the *choices* always are evaluated.**

The expanded `in` macro evaluates the *choices* sequentially. If it reaches a choice that is eql to the first argument, it returns a true value without evaluating any more
forms.

In contrast, the `in-func` function will evaluate all the *choices* at the time the function is called.

Comment: that means if my functions are referentially transparent, there is no difference between macros and functions?

Answer (score 3):

The two other answers are correct, but to make things more concrete, consider this interaction:

```
CL-USER(1): (defmacro in ...)
IN
CL-USER(2): (defun in-func ...)
IN-FUNC
CL-USER(3): (defvar *count* 0)
*COUNT*
CL-USER(4): (defun next () (incf *count*))
NEXT
CL-USER(5): (in 2 1 2 3 (next))
T
CL-USER(6): *count*
0
CL-USER(7): (in-func 2 1 2 3 (next))
T
CL-USER(8): *count*
1
```